# CSS selector - Select first option of required select

Tags: html, css

What is the proper (CSS3) method for grabbing the first option of a select that is required. (i.e. I don't want this rule to apply to select elements that are not required). I am trying to avoid adding a class to each required element.

Example: I want only the Please select option selected for the fontSize element, but **not** the Please select option for fontColor.

Edit:

I want all required selects to behave like this, and non-required selects to have all their options be black.

[image]

Test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Have also tried select:first-child:required but this selects all the options in a required select */
      option:first-child:required
      {
        color: #FF0000 !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select required name="fontSize">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="9">9 px</option>
      <option value="10">10 px</option>
      <option value="11">11 px</option>
      <option value="12">12 px</option>
      <option value="13">13 px</option>
      <option value="14">14 px</option>
      <option value="15" selected="">15 px</option>
      <option value="16">16 px</option>
    </select>

    <select name="fontColor">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To style the first `option` of a required `select`, I would simply use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), followed by the [`:first-child` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child).

```css
select[required] option:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select required name="fontSize">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="9">9 px</option>
<option value="10">10 px</option>
<option value="11">11 px</option>
<option value="12">12 px</option>
<option value="13">13 px</option>
<option value="14">14 px</option>
<option value="15" selected="">15 px</option>
<option value="16">16 px</option>
</select>

<select name="fontColor">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works exactly as expected - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I misunderstood the question.

You can do it using nth-type selector or first-child selector.

Pass a class to the select tag.

```
<select class="sel" required name="fontSize">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="9">9 px</option>
  <option value="10">10 px</option>
  <option value="11">11 px</option>
  <option value="12">12 px</option>
  <option value="13">13 px</option>
  <option value="14">14 px</option>
  <option value="15" selected="">15 px</option>
  <option value="16">16 px</option>
</select>




select[name="fontSize"] option:first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

or

```
select[name="fontSize"] option:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: ...? I'm guessing the `p:first-child` selector is not going to select an `option` element...

Comment: it was just an example. Let me change it to be more relevant

Comment: select[required] option:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}

This is the code that op wants.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to **target** the first `select` element with CSS, what you are looking for is the **[:first-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/)** pseudo-selector:

```css
select:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select required name="fontSize">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="9">9 px</option>
  <option value="10">10 px</option>
  <option value="11">11 px</option>
  <option value="12">12 px</option>
  <option value="13">13 px</option>
  <option value="14">14 px</option>
  <option value="15" selected="">15 px</option>
  <option value="16">16 px</option>
</select>

<select name="fontColor">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

If instead you are looking to target the first **option** of the first `select` box, you can **chain** the pseudo-selectors:

```css
select:first-of-type option:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select required name="fontSize">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="9">9 px</option>
  <option value="10">10 px</option>
  <option value="11">11 px</option>
  <option value="12">12 px</option>
  <option value="13">13 px</option>
  <option value="14">14 px</option>
  <option value="15" selected="">15 px</option>
  <option value="16">16 px</option>
</select>

<select name="fontColor">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

This will only style the 'Please select' of the first select box (`fontSize`), leaving the 'Please select' of `fontColor` unmodified.

Based on your **edit**, you can target the first **option** of any **required** `select` field by using the square brackets `[required]` [**attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) in conjunction with the `:first-of-type` pseudo-selector.

```css
select[required] option:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select required name="fontSize">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="9">9 px</option>
  <option value="10">10 px</option>
  <option value="11">11 px</option>
  <option value="12">12 px</option>
  <option value="13">13 px</option>
  <option value="14">14 px</option>
  <option value="15" selected="">15 px</option>
  <option value="16">16 px</option>
</select>

<select name="fontColor">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That's not working, because you're applying `:first-of-type` to `select`, not `option`...

Comment: I believe that's what the OP is looking for: "*I want only the Please select option selected for the fontSize element, but not the Please select option for fontColor.*"

Comment: Read again. The OP is asking for "the first option of a select that is required".

Comment: A bit confusing, but I've updated my answer to cover this as well, leaving the original answer just in case :)

Comment: You should probably be using comments to solicit clarification instead of adding answers...

Comment: That there are so many questions, including those stating they dont' understand the question, is reason enough for this question to be closed.

Comment: @Rob - Thank you I tend to agree, I did not intend for this question to be misleading. I've edited it accordingly.