# CSS to target first option in p-dropdown primeng

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I am using primeng in my app and I want to customize just one option in the p-dropdown but not sure how to go about it.

```
<p-dropdown id="dropdown" [options]="options" optionLabel="name" optionValue="name"></p-dropdown>
```

I have this as my css:

```
p-dropdown ::ng-deep .p-dropdown-item {
    /* my custom css for one option only */
}
```

and I have tried using :first, :first-child, :first-of-type, :nth-child, :nth-of-type to see if I can target just one option but it still applies the css to all the options in the dropdown. How can I go about this?

PS: This question has nothing to do with the select element and everything to do with the primeng p-dropdown element. Please read the question in its entirety.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694271/modify-select-so-only-the-first-one-is-gray or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769300/css-selector-select-first-option-of-required-select ?

Comment: Perhaps related https://stackoverflow.com/q/46786986/125981 and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55542222/125981

Comment: @TylerH its different because I am using the primeng library

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss perharps not. I am implementing the primeng library and I have already implemented ng-deep but that is not the question I am asking

Comment: That probably still compiles to HTML select elements though, no?

Comment: @TylerH no, a couple divs and spans, no select elements used

Comment: So then it's just how to style a div? Can you share your compiled markup?

Comment: I changed the tag from p-dropdown to angular to see if you can get more attention on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that there are `p-dropdownitem` element and `p-dropdown-item` CSS class:

```
<p-dropdownitem ...>
  <li class="p-dropdown-item" ...>
    <span ...>LABEL</span>
  </li>
</p-dropdownitem>
```

so, `:first-item` should be applied to the element and not its child element with that class:

```
p-dropdown ::ng-deep p-dropdownitem:first-child .p-dropdown-item {
  /* my custom css for one option only */
}
```

hope this helped :)

Comment: thank you so much! this worked perfect! I'll have to look more carefully next time